# How to start a Activity after downloading the file?

Tags: android, progressdialog

In my android application in activity I am checking the if file exists or not. If not I want to download as well as display progress dialog. Once download completed dismiss the progress dialog and continue the activity.

Comment: You can use the first option in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/2652124)
To start an activity, you can start it after `progressDialog.dismiss()` in `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Check if exists - if not, then start an `AsyncTask`. There in the `doInBackground` method download it and in the `onProgressUpdate` method set up your progress bar.

Comment: What's your real need? 1.file existence checking, 2. download with progress, 3. start new activity. Which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(Context.ActivityName,Target.class);// Eg: new Intent(ThisClass.this,TargetClass.class);
mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
```

use like this

Answer (score 1):

> How to start a Activity after downloading the file?

Probably i assume that you are using `AsyncTask` for your task.

Then this can be simply done with onPostExecute() method that  is invoked when your task is done (doInBackround() method finished). Method is synchronized with Main (UI) Thread and allows operations with UI.

So in this method you can put something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(<context>, TargetActivity.class);
//i.putExtra("key",<data>) // if you want wrap some additional data
<context>.startActivity(i);
```